# How to use "img" tag in a "phtml" file?

Tags: image-preview

I'm trying to display an image from a phtml file. The following doesn't work.

```
<?php <img src="<?php echo $adress ;?>" /> ?>
```

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loose the php tags around the `img` tag.

Use simply this:

```
<img src="<?php echo $adress ;?>" />
```